# Browserify result from npm build can not be instantiated in test file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on converting a vanilla ES6 WebGL library to a package and am having some trouble / don't really know what I'm doing.

With the current library, we use browserify to compile it into a single file which is then copied over to our Ember project which is then mushed into our vendor file. When we develop the library we simply reference the compiled file in an HTML file local to the repo to debug and test.

Using an HTML test file local to the library is really nice because the Ember project is cumbersome and not ideal for testing the WebGL code.

I would like to have the library as a package.json or bower.json dependency of the Ember project so the workflow between the two projects is more mature and smooth. BUT I would like to maintain the debug workflow for the library so I don't have to deal with Ember constantly (Unless there is a better workflow out there for such a situation I don't know about).

Right now I'm having some troubles getting my npm build to properly browserify the library so it can be used in my HTML test file.

I've made a watered down version of the library's architecture in a demo repo [here](https://github.com/nhoughto5/NPM_PackageTest) for you to see if you wish.

But, in essence, in the source folder I have two really boring classes, HelloWorld and TestClass.

**src/HelloWorld.js**

```
import TestClass from './TestClass';

class HelloWorld{
  constructor(){

  }

  hello(){
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    let t = new TestClass();
    p.innerHTML = "Hello World " + t.TestMember();
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
}

module.exports = HelloWorld;
```

**src/TestClass.js**

```
class TestClass{
  constructor(){
    this.member = 5;
  }

  TestMember(){
    return "Test Member is: " + this.member;
  }
}

module.exports = TestClass;
```

These are referenced in the library's entry point in src/index.js

**src/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
  TestClass: require('./TestClass'),
  HelloWorld: require('./HelloWorld')
};
```

Here is my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webgl-render-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Render Library",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "build-js": "browserify lib/index.js > demo/RenderLibrary.js",
    "build": "babel ./src -d ./lib && npm run build-js",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "test": "nyc mocha --require babel-core/register"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nhoughto5/NPM_PackageTest.git"
  },
  "author": "Anon",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nhoughto5/NPM_PackageTest/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nhoughto5/NPM_PackageTeste#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.1",
    "eslint": "4.19.0",
    "mocha": "5.0.4",
    "nyc": "11.6.0"
  },
  "nyc": {
    "reporter": [
      "lcov",
      "text"
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the scripts section I have `build` which babels all of the source files into the lib directory, and then the `build-js` script is run which in theory should browserify all of those files into the single RenderLibrary.js so I can test it in my test HTML file which you can see here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Package Test</title>
    <script src="RenderLibrary.js"></script>
    <script>
        function btnClick(){
            var obj = new HelloWorld();
            obj.hello();
            console.log("Hello Again");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="btnClick()">Press Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This all nicely compiles but in my test file I can't instantiate an instance of the two test classes.

When I click the `Press Me` button I get a nice `Uncaught ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined`even though the compiled RenderLibrary.js file does define it.

Comment: Lovely question btw with link to repo and everything. Gold star! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rethink this a bit. The reason you use `browserify` in the first place is to be able to write browser code in node style, i.e. using `require`.

So given `packageTest.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Package Test</title>
    <script src="testbundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="testbutton">Press Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You should really do `browserify lib/test.js > demo/testbundle.js`, where `test.js` contains code for the event handler. Also, in `test.js` you should `require` the `HelloWorld` class. It could look something like:

```
const domready = require('domready')                  
const HelloWorld = require('.').HelloWorld            

domready(function () {                                
  const button = document.getElementById('testbutton')
  button.onclick = function () {                      
    const obj = new HelloWorld()                      
    obj.hello()                                       
  }                                                   
})
```

Result:

[image]

I've tested it using your repository. Pull request made here https://github.com/nhoughto5/NPM_PackageTest/pull/3